# Android manage fragment circles

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using Fragments in a FragmentActivity with a FragmentManager.
I need to keep the last modifications in the fragment.

If I use `FragmentTransaction.replace();` It will destroy the Fragment and reset it.

I decided to hide the previous Fragment and show the next one.
But the Fragment can be destroyed by an income call or a device rotation and they can't be shown anymore.

My question is how can I manage this?

- If I use `show()`, `hide()` I need to forbid the fragment's destruction
- If I use `fragmentTransaction.replace()` I need to save the last state.

The second solution looks better but I have no idea how to proceed.
Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed it.

THe trick is to use FragmentTransition.replace() and FragmentTransition.addTobackStack(null);

And overide onBackPressed of the activity like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{

}
```

Hope it will help!